# How to retrieve URL for Bitrise Test Reports Add on

Tags: bitrise

We have developed a bitrise pipeline which runs tests and exports results for our mobile app. We are using the Bitrise test report add on but I cannot seem to generate a URL for the add on.
The aim is to create a report link for slack notification step, does anyone know how to use the Bitrise API for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no official API for that right now, but you can construct the URL Testing Addon Login URL based on the build's ID:

```
https://app.bitrise.io/app/[APPID]/addon/addons-testing/login_page?build_slug=[BUILDID]
```

You can see this URL if you right click on the Test Report addon button and copy the URL.

Using the environment variables available during a build, you can construct this URL like this:

```
https://app.bitrise.io/app/$BITRISE_APP_SLUG/addon/addons-testing/login_page?build_slug=$BITRISE_BUILD_SLUG
```

Note: this is an undocumented URL, which means it's not guaranteed that it'll not change in the future.